# Better/faster way to do these field calculations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Anyone know a better way to do these field calculations in a SQL Server View?

```
SELECT         
TCQ.Generic, 

TPM.WRITTEN_PRM / ((100 - TPM.[CO-PART]) / 100 * CASE WHEN TPM.Factor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE TPM.[Factor] END) AS Gross100_WRITTEN_PRM,  

TPM.EARNED_PRM / ((100 - TPM.[CO-PART]) / 100 * CASE WHEN TPM.Factor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE TPM.[Factor] END) AS Gross100_EARNED_PRM, 
TC.Generic = GS.Generic

(FROM table table table blah blah...)
```

Comment: You could simplify the `case` statement by using `coalesce` like so:  `TPM.WRITTEN_PRM/((100 - TPM.[CO-PART])/coalesce(TPM.Factor*100, 100)) AS Gross100_WRITTEN_PRM,`

Comment: You could use `cross apply values` to greatly simplify.

Answer (score 2):

You can use COALESCE()  or ISNULL() instead of CASE.

```
SELECT         
  TCQ.Generic,
    TPM.WRITTEN_PRM / ((100 - TPM.[CO-PART]) / 100 * coalesce ( TPM.Factor, 1) ) AS Gross100_WRITTEN_PRM,  
    TPM.EARNED_PRM / ((100 - TPM.[CO-PART]) / 100 * coalesce ( TPM.Factor, 1)) AS Gross100_EARNED_PRM, 
    TC.Generic = GS.Generic

  (FROM table table table blah blah...)
```

Comment: Thanks, Gudlk; seems to run about the same speed though, maybe a touch slower

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor as something like the following - untested of course

```
select         
TPM.WRITTEN_PRM / f.v as Gross100_WRITTEN_PRM,  
TPM.EARNED_PRM / f.v as Gross100_EARNED_PRM, 
from
tables
cross apply (values(100 - TPM.[CO-PART]/isnull(TPM.[Factor],1)*100))f(v)
```

Comment: Thanks, Stu, that's a tad faster